# AttributeError or ImportError in python calculator program

Tags: python, importerror, attributeerror

I am writing a calculator program with python, and i keep getting an error message 
`AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'response_txt'`

```
from tkinter import *




class Application(Frame):
""" GUI application calculator. """ 
def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialize the frame. """
    super(Application, self).__init__(master)  

    # Adds the grid layout manager
    self.grid()

    # The result string
    self.response_str = ""

    #sets up the controls in the frame
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    """ Create and sequence """

    #Text Sequence
    self.sequence_txt = Text(self, height = 1, width = 30, wrap=WORD)
    self.sequence_txt.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    # Configure the Text to center
    self.sequence_txt.tag_config("center_align", justify='center')

    # Configure the Text to center
    self.response_txt.tag_config("center_align", justify='center')

    ###buttons
    # Button 1
    Button(self,
           bg='1',
           command = self.one_btn_clicked,
           height = 2
           ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)

#buttons clicked
def one_btn_clicked(self):
    """This method is run when the one button gets clicked"""
    #append a 1
    self.response_str+="1"
    #update text
    self.response_txt.delete(0.0, END)
    self.response_txt.insert(0.0, self.response_str, "center_align")
    #add number
    self.compare_sequences();
#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When i ran this through the module, it gave me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'response_txt'
```

I tried importing a submodule like this:

```
`import self.response_txt`
```

And then it gave me this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'self'
```

I really need this to work, school assignment due tomorrow. Any ideas are appreciated, I am very new to programming. I am also aware that the program is not really that close to done, but before I can move to any other steps I need to make sure what I did here will work in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to intitalise self.response_txt. Furthermore, '1' is not a valid argument for bg in the code:

```
Button(self,
           bg='1',
           command = self.one_btn_clicked,
           height = 2
           ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
```

Corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *




class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI application calculator. """ 
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  

        # Adds the grid layout manager
        self.grid()

        # The result string
        self.response_str = ""

        #sets up the controls in the frame
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create and sequence """

        #Text Sequence
        self.sequence_txt = Text(self, height = 1, width = 30, wrap=WORD)
        self.sequence_txt.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.response_txt = Text(self, height = 1, width = 30, wrap=WORD)
        self.response_txt.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        # Configure the Text to center
        self.sequence_txt.tag_config("center_align", justify='center')

        # Configure the Text to center
        self.response_txt.tag_config("center_align", justify='center')

        ###buttons
        # Button 1
        Button(self,
               bg='white',
               command = self.one_btn_clicked,
               height = 2
               ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)

    #buttons clicked
    def one_btn_clicked(self):
        """This method is run when the one button gets clicked"""
        #append a 1
        self.response_str+="1"
        #update text
        self.response_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.response_txt.insert(0.0, self.response_str, "center_align")
        #add number
        self.compare_sequences();
#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also you haven't created compare_sequences function.

Comment: Ok, that worked, now how would I make a number "1" show up on the button in the tkinter window? And what would the "compare_sequences" function you mentioned do?

Comment: Ah, I think I see that the "compare_sequences" would make the "1" show up on the button like I want it to. How would I add that function?

Comment: Ok. Now I know that i was wrong about the compare_sequences function. I know what it would do and I don't think I need it for a calculator program. How would I make the number "1" show up on the button in the tkinter window??

Comment: By passing text = "1" as a parameter to the button function.

Comment: Button(self,
               text = "1",
               bg='white',
               command = self.one_btn_clicked,
               height = 2
               ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)